# How to get first parent path of a branch using github API?

Tags: git, github

Using GitHub API, is there a way to get commit ids associated with first parent alone?

Simply, I want to get the output of

```
git log --first-parent origin/branch_name
```

command through API.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there seems to be no built-in way to do this (e.g. a param to ["Compare two commits"](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits?apiVersion=2022-11-28#compare-two-commits) would be nice).

However you can get `parents` from the ["Get a commit" (`/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits/{ref}`)](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-commit) API response and then follow the chain back yourself calling this repeatedly.

To start with a branch name, first find the head commit of the branch using ["Get a branch" (`/repos/{owner}/{repo}/branches/{branch}`)](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/branches/branches?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-branch).

This assumes the `parents` list in the API response is in the right order which I have not checked (the docs don't seem to specify) but would very much hope is true.